# Flex alert with TextInput as well as buttons

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know if it is possible to add other controls to a Flex 3 Alert? What I need is a modal dialoge that allows the user to type in a filename before clicking OK or CANCEL. This seems like it would be best achieved with an Alert but in the documentation I don't see an obvious way to add a TextInput (or any other control except a Button). I'd rather not have to reinvent the wheel but if I have to then hey, I'll do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a flex Title Window. The Alert allows configuring of buttons and text of the buttons. There are some examples of the title window [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/TitleWindow.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe creating your own component to serve this purpose is your only route.  You can always use the styles of the alert dialog though so it will look like all other alerts and keep a similar feel throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "PopUpManager" class to make an Alert as per your requirements,
[Example here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000696.html) or [custom pop up](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/20/creating-custom-pop-up-windows-with-the-popupmanager-class-redux/)